# List the output type of all the projects in a solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there any way to list all the projects in a solution including the output type of each of them?

Comment: What is a output type?

Comment: Are you going to do it from within Visual Studio, or outside of it?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy: Project Properties > Application > Output Type (e.g. Console Application, Class Library, etc.)

Comment: @felix-b I can do it from Visual Studio or outside it

Comment: Just do it using notepad++ or whatever your fav. tool is. Search for files *.csproj files in root folder and search in content <OutputType>

Comment: Thanks 3615, I see that the .proj files are XML. I can look for the tag <OutputType> and retrieve the value there.

Comment: I have obtained the list by going to the root folder and executing "grep -R "<OutputType>" >D:\Projects.txt", of cours you need to have the grep command installed to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more programmatic way of doing this in a standalone program, which doesn't depend on any external programs being installed.

With the help of [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Roslyn%20Overview) and its [Workspace API](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/09/12/learn-roslyn-now-part-6-working-with-workspaces/), you can load a solution file, enumerate over contained projects, and retrieve output kind of each one.

The following NuGet packages will be required:

- [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.WorkSpaces.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common/2.4.0)
- [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/2.4.0)
- [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces/2.4.0)

And the code will look like this:

```
string slnFilePath = "..."; // path to SLN file

MSBuildWorkspace workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(slnFilePath).Result;

foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{project.Name} : {project.CompilationOptions.OutputKind}");
}
```

where `OutputKind` is of an enum defined as follows:

```
public enum OutputKind
{
    ConsoleApplication,
    WindowsApplication,
    DynamicallyLinkedLibrary,
    NetModule,
    WindowsRuntimeMetadata,
    WindowsRuntimeApplication,
}
```